# Regarding the usage of "at" in "A chance at that dream"

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

I went through the [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/at) as well as [Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/at) dictionary, and I still couldn't find what definition of *at* is being used in:

> The great debts we pay for a desperate chance *at* that dream.

Source: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NXHwelwmQPA&t=5m&2s) Youtube video.

EDIT: The second definition from Webster's dictionary doesn't really help in the context above, aiming a "chance" at a "dream" seems rather ambiguous to me.

Comment: At the very least, we should know which dictionaries you've already tried. Even better, you might explain why none of those definitions seemed to fit this usage.

Comment: We usually speak of having *a chance **of** [doing something]* (NOUN = a possibility, an opportunity), but in your exact context ***chance*** has more the sense of a VERB ***attempt, go, stab, shot*** (to realise that dream, to make it happen). All those synonymous verbs take ***at*** rather than ***of***, which I guess is why your cited writer chose that preposition. It's not great phrasing though, imho. Whatever - the relevant "definition" for ***at*** there would be the same as, for example, *Let me have a try **at** answering the question* (identifying the *target, aim* of an action).

Comment: @ColinFine: Agreed in principle. But isn't it really a fairly standard usage of ***at*** alluding to (metaphorical) "location, direction, target" of an "action"? Or maybe a chance / opportunity to *perform* the relevant goal-oriented action (which in context is assumed to be almost synonymous with *achieving* the goal).

Comment: @ColinFine Webster's Third has the following definition of *chance* (noun, sense 2): "a circumstantial situation affording the possibility of effectuating some objective : *opportunity*", with sub-definition b.: "an opening for a try, venture, or grasp", under which there's an example: *10 years after his death historians will get **a chance at** his personal file*. Would that satisfice? I doubt this is anything other than that, just without the verb *get* or *have*, which might well have been present in the original. At worst, it's FumbleFingers' *at* in the metaphorical sense of "toward".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start by analyzing the phrase:

> a chance at that dream

Per the answer to [this other question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100014/chance-of-gerund-vs-chance-at-gerund), the phrase *a chance at [X]* means *an opportunity to achieve [X]*. This fits with one of the definitions of *chance*: "a situation favoring some purpose; opportunity".<sup>1</sup> *Dream* in this context means "a strongly desired goal or purpose".<sup>2</sup>

So "a chance at that dream" translates to "an opportunity to achieve that goal".

Now let's look at that definition of *at* from Merriam-Webster that you weren't sure about:

> (Entry 1 of 6)
>   **2.** —used as a function word to indicate the goal of an indicated or implied action or motion

(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/at)

We've already established that *dream* is a "goal". And while a *chance* or opportunity is not **itself** an action, it encourages a course of action or makes it possible; in other words, it **implies** an action. So the *at* in your example phrase is "used as a function word to indicate the goal of an...implied action".

In short, the definition fits.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chance, entry 1, definition 2</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dream, definition 4a</sup>